# Monitoring Recurring Payments

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, subscription, billing, recurring-billing

Some websites are able to monitor recurring monthly payments and show me when a payment was made or failed and possibly even an id for the payment in their billing system. I'd like to do the same thing. When I searched online though, most of the online payment processing services I find only tell my website if the first payment was made. Google Checkout says if a payment fails, they will send me an email, that's all. I want to automate this process though.

Are there any online payment processing services that offer a way, perhaps through an API, to track from my website the recurring payment information: time of payment, date, status, etc.?

Or perhaps is there another way websites might be monitoring their recurring payments that I'm unaware of? (such as an API with their bank)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Authorize.net offers a "silent post feature" as well as a "get subscription status":

[Getting status on canceled/expired credit cards for recurring billing with authorize.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997942/getting-status-on-canceled-expired-credit-cards-for-recurring-billing-with-autho)